# How to get the response of a post api call then show error on the page

Tags: angular, typescript, api, post, error-handling

```
const tokenClean = sessionStorage.getItem('token')?.replace(/[:{}"]/g, '');
  const tokenFinal = tokenClean?.replace(/token/g, '');
  const headers = {
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${tokenFinal}`,
    'Body': '{}',
    
  };
  this.http.post(apiUrl + "token/vendor/request/getproductlist", headers, { headers })
  .subscribe((data: any) =>
{ this.listDropDown2 = data; }
```

This is my code for calling an api post request, How do i get the error then show it on the page? If there is one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Angular's `HttpClient` makes use of the RxJs observable handlers, watching for an error in any HTTP call is the same as watching for an error in any other observable, e.g. by providing a second callback function as an argument to `subscribe()` ([docs](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable)).

*Note: The answer demonstrates this by providing an 'observer' object as an argument to `subscribe()` which contains the success (`next`) and error (`error`) handlers as keys on this object*

This returns a `HttpErrorResponse` class ([docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse)) which contains all of the metadata about the error:

```
  postProductList() {
    const tokenClean = sessionStorage.getItem('token')?.replace(/[:{}"]/g, '');
    const tokenFinal = tokenClean?.replace(/token/g, '');
    const headers = {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${tokenFinal}`,
      'Body': '{}',
    };

    this.http.post(
      apiUrl + "token/vendor/request/getproductlist",
      headers,
      { headers }
    )
      .subscribe({
        next: (data: any) => {
          // any API success handling logic goes here (e.g. for http codes 2xx and 3xx)
          this.listDropDown2 = data;
        },
        error: (httpError: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          // any API error handling logic goes here (e.g. for http codes 4xx and 5xx)
          const errorValue: any | null = httpError.error;
          const errorCode: number = httpError.status;
          console.error(`Endpoint returned error ${errorValue} with status code ${errorCode}`)
        }
      })
  }
```

Comment: You probably want to either pass an observer object or use pipe to catch errors. Passing multiple function to `subscribe()` call is deprecated already.

Comment: Very true, I would typically use `catchError` and `tap` to remain declarative, but didn't want to overload the answer with multiple concepts! I have however reworked the answer to use the observer pattern which is still in keeping with the imperative nature of the question. Thanks for your comment!